# Git push - Does it make files unavailable for sometime?

Tags: git

I have a repo in production.
I have made some changes on dev.
I wish to update the production with those changes.

However, people are already working on the production env.

My question is:

If we commit some files, and I push, what will happen while people are working on production?

Will all files be affected, or it will only push those specific files?

Will the files be unaccessible for some period?

Hope you understand my concerns/questions.

**Update: (more details)**
Developing php web applications.

We work on DEV local and remote servers. We have a bare repo with two branches, dev and master. Once all it's ok on DEV, we locally marge dev into master, and we `push the master`.

By `push the master`, I mean, `we push to the bare repo, that will detected we are on the master branch (via hooks) and update (pull from repo) the  production env`.

Hope it's more clear.

Comment: You should never directly use a repository as production environment. Have a repository which you push to and let production pull from it. Also, you should _never_ push into a repository with an associated working copy.

Comment: I think it depend on your technology. for ex: if `PHP`, your changes will be applied immediately, but `java` need restarting server.

Comment: I've updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Only commited files will be pushed.
If more then one person commits same file it could cause conflicts in the repository and would require to resolve them using mergetools and difftools.

Git is a pretty smart tool. Once I worked with my collegues and we all commited same file, but changed different lines, it merged automatically and there was no problem, however it is risky to do so.

The best way to prevent conflicts is using separated branches for different features or different developers who work on the project and when ready merge them.
If more then one developer works on same branch a good practice would be to make a pull from the repository before starting to modify the files and commiting.

Comment: My question was more about users, and less about developers. Thanks, however, for taking the time to reply.

Comment: No problem, so you would like to know what will be the current state of repository if someone who has no idea about git will access it, right? Do I get it now?

Comment: Not quite that. I will try with an example: You change something in your code, then you push those changes and changes are reflected on the production. Imagine, for instance, `at exactly that time` one  end user, accessing your crafted back-office, is updating a database record, and you push a new version of "connectBD file" at that `same time`. What will happen to that database record? What will the enduser see? I presume, that the best we can is to provide some sort of lock, like: "System is under maintenance, please wait."

Comment: I see now, I would say it can't read it `exact same time`, it will always be right before or right after your commit, if it will be right before, probably he won't connect, because your file was changed right after he loaded it, and if it is right after he will just get last version that includes your commit and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It will only affect files which are changed.

What will happen while people are working on production?

It is difficult to answer this questions. It completely depends on the system/platform.

I would suggest you never push directly to production. Remote repository and production files should be separate. You should take artifacts from remote repository after pushing and deploy it to production (intimating everyone in advance/ downtime if required) with the appropriate change control mechanism.

Comment: Thanks. I've update my question. Can you please confirm if you suggestion still applies?

Comment: I have not worked with hooks but it seems you are doing the right thing. Only thing important here is that, if the change you are introducing is significant, users might get surprised if not notified in advance.